# Django 2 register confirmation email directs to homepage instead of login page

Tags: django, django-views, django-2.0

I am setting up my Django 2.1 application so that when a user registers, they first are sent a confirmation email with a link to click on to activate the account.

So far I have managed to set it up (with the help of another post) and everything works up until the point of clicking on the activation email.

When I copy and paste the link into the browser, it directs me to the main landing page, not the login page.

Is anybody able to look over my views and see if there is something missing?

```
def register_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Post request.
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()

        mail_subject = 'Activate your account.'
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        uid = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode()
        token = account_activation_token.make_token(user)
        activation_link = "{0}/?uid={1}&token{2}".format(current_site, uid, token)
        message = "Hello {0},\n {1}".format(user.username, activation_link)
        to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
        email.send()
        return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')

       else:
           # Get request.
           form = UserRegisterForm()
       return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

def activate(request, uidb64, token):
        try:
            uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()
            user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            user = None
        if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
            # activate user and login:
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created {username}. Login.')
            return render(request, 'users/login.html')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

urls.py

```
path('activate/<str:uid>/<str:token>',
    user_views.activate,
    name='activate'),
```

tokens.py

```
class AccountActivationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) +
            six.text_type(timestamp) +
            six.text_type(user.is_active)
        )

account_activation_token = AccountActivationTokenGenerator()
```

Comment: why is it {0}/?uid={1}&token{2}, not token={2} ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't be able to confirm that the whole registration feature works, but to answer your specific question, your code is creating an activation_link which is set to:

```
activation_link = "{0}/?uid={1}&token{2}".format(current_site, uid, token)
```

which if you look closely, it is creating something like:

```
http://example.com/?uid=....&token=....
```

but your path in the urls.py is

```
path('activate/<str:uid>/<str:token>', user_views.activate, name='activate')
```

which means it is expecting something like

```
http://example.com/activate/..../....
```

Therefore, the fix is simply to change the activation_link to

```
activation_link = "{0}/activate/{1}/{2}".format(current_site, uid, token)
```

Again, just asking the specific question you are asking.

Your question aside, you may want to look into existing packages like django-registration or a more complete package like django-allauth (which supports the registration flow and social logins if later needed)

Comment: Thank you for your extremely clear answer, just brilliant. Yes I can obviously see why it wasn't working now. I will look into those packages. Just one last question, I am still not going through to the login page because I am getting an error `name 'uidb64' is not defined` I am assuming from the line `uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64).decode()` Do you have any idea how to remedy this?

Comment: When I change it to `urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64=uid).decode()` the error is resolved but I'm directed to `'Activation link is invalid!'`

Comment: That’s a very different question, probably for another post, but unless you have a custom User model, the default one uses normal integers as primary keys so the UUID won’t work. You need to decode the UUID to extract the actual user ID. As I said, this is a solved problem so no need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Got it, I'm going to use allauth but thanks so much for your help regardless.